# Display 0 instead of blank if no record found in table

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, where-clause

i want to display '0' when my query will return no records instead of blank

```
select count(*) AS count
from
    tbl a
where
    a.Id in ('45')
group by a.Id;
```

Comment: i tried this one also select count(a.id) AS count
from
    tbl a
where
    a.Id in ('45')
group by a.Id;

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(a.Id) AS count
from  tbl a
where a.Id in ('45');
```

The important bit is remove GROUP BY.
But it would be better to restrict counting to one field

Comment: i can't remove GROUP BY

Comment: are you bringin more than '45' then?

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM ( 
SELECT *
FROM
    tbl a
WHERE
    a.Id IN ('45')
GROUP BY a.Id) X;
```

Comment: sorry i can not go with this query ...and thanks for reply

Comment: it will be more better for other people to help, if you specify reason why you can not go with this query

Answer (score 0):

I guess your query should be like this:

```
   select ifnull(count(*), 0) AS count
from
    tbl a
where
    a.Id in ('45')
group by a.Id;
```

See the sample attached how you can do this:

```
mysql> select ifnull(count(*), 0) as counttotal from Persons;
+------------+
| counttotal |
+------------+
|          0 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Murali your query  have no  GROUP BY